# Is it possible to host Cassandra nodes on-premise (vs cloud)?

Tags: cassandra, client, distributed, decentralized-applications

I'm trying to build a Decentralised social media platform using Cassandra. To do this I would like the instances or nodes of the Cassandra database to be hosted on the clients side rather then having it hosted on the cloud. I would like to know if it would be possible for the user to somehow run an instance on their side with part of the data. This will allow the information to be distributed between many computers globally.

Comment: A friendly reminder that Stack Overflow is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. If you post it there, I'd be happy to help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy Cassandra nodes:

- on-premise,
- on a private cloud,
- on a public cloud, or
- a hybrid environment of on-premise + cloud.

It is also possible to deploy Cassandra on any combination of the above. Cheers!